# Изменение прокрутки изображений в Fancybox

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, как поменять тип анимации при прокрутке изображений в плагине Fancybox?
Нужно, чтобы просто менялась плавно картинка, как [тут](http://fancybox.net/home): (раздел Image gallery)
По умолчанию картинка идёт справа налево, потом затухает и появляется следующая.

Такой настройки в плагине не нашёл, в вебе рецепта не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Там вот такой код стоит:

```
$("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'titlePosition'     : 'over',
        'titleFormat'       : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
            return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' +  (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + ' ' + title + '</span>';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте при инициализации плагина использовать опции - transitionIn, transitionOut

Пример

```
$("a[rel=gallery]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn' : 'none',
    'transitionOut' : 'none'
});
```

Comment: не работает

Comment: Можете накидать то что у вас есть в jsFiddle? Думаю так будет и проще и быстрее разобраться с проблемой которая у Вас возникла.